# About the product of two uniformly continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I am interested in the following question:

Assume $f,g: [0,+\infty)\to\mathbf R$ are both uniformly continuous, and $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to+\infty$. Can this guarantee that $h(x)\equiv f(x)g(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty)$?

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: Any hint?  Well $f(x)=x$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I am not sure if I get your point. Would you please clarify a bit? Many thanks!

Comment: $g(x)=(x+1)^{-1/2}$ or $g(x)=(\sin x)/\sqrt{x}$

Comment: You don't need any more hints since Ryszard's answer is enough.  But, in thinking about this problem, one key was to realize where a counterexample might arise.  Otherwise you might just try random combinations.  If $h:[0,\infty) \to\mathbb  R$ is continuous and the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)$ exists then $h$ must be uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.  So any example that works has to avoid that. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077440/proving-that-f-is-uniformly-continuous-on-0-infty

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks!

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I don't understand your first example. The function $x\mapsto\frac x{\sqrt{x+1}}$ *is* uniformly continuous.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  Yes, the first example $h(x)=x(1+x)^{-\frac12}$ seems to be a Lipschitz function ... if I had the patience to compute its derivative.  But Ryszard's second example  $h(x)=\sqrt x \sin x$ is really very nice and dramatically not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Yes, the second example is beautiful.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry for the first example. I was too fast.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson The first example is Indeed a failure,  The function satisfies the Lipschitz condition as $$x(1+x)^{-1/2}=(1+x)^{1/2}-(1+x)^{-1/2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question does not need an "answer" since the example given by @RyszardSzwarc completes the assignment most elegantly.

But that never stops anyone with a particularly strong pedantic inclination.  I learned from L.C. Young who was a professor at Madison and the son of a pair of famous British mathematicians of something he called "lemon squeezing" in one of his memoirs.

Given a problem or a theorem, a mathematician is expected to gnaw and chew at it like a dog on an old bone.  Or, to use his much better metaphor, squeeze it for just a wee bit more, similar in the way one can always get just one more drop of lemon juice from a lemon if you try a bit harder.

So we know that the product of two uniformly continuous functions on a compact interval $[a,b]$ must be uniformly continuous, but that the product of such functions on the unbounded interval $[0,\infty)$ need not be.  Even if one of the pair has a zero limit at $\infty$.  End of assignment.  Time for a beer.

Or, maybe, squeeze that lemon.  If you wish to transition from a student to a research mathematician then you really must always get used to doing that lemon squeezing...along with the beer if you must.

> **Problem I.**  Give necessary and sufficient conditions on a function $h:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ so that it can be written as a product $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$
> where   both functions $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$.

> **Problem II.**  Give necessary and sufficient conditions on a function $h:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ so that it can be written as a product $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$
> where    (i) both functions $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$, and
> (ii)  $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = 0$.

For Problem I you might wish to consult this reference:

> *On the Product of two Uniformly Continuous Functions on the Line*.   Ernest S. Elyash, George Laush and  Norman Levine. The American
> Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 67, No. 3 (Mar., 1960), pp. 265-267
> https://doi.org/10.2307/2309692